# HTML text related formatting

Tags: html, css, html-table, formatting

[image]

I have an html website. I use Dreamweaver. In order to make a section in an article I used tables to put text and an image. But tables are not rounded like I wanted. So I am posting this so you can tell me what is the proper code to achieve what the picture shows.

image: on the left is the what I would like to make. On the right you see the elements that I will use. So I want some how the middle elements to repeat themselves in order to form the background. But I want also this background of the table to be able to have text (like in the image).

Comment: I don't know what should be the title. I don't know much from these things.

Comment: Is there anything that you tried yet to solve that problem?

Comment: What people would usually do is to divide the border in tables as well. This way you only need a really small, rounded, image for the border.. the rest are background color.

Comment: So you voted down my post assuming that I didn't tried anything to solve the problem? I created a whole scheme in illustrator in order to be able to explain my problem and you think that I've not tried anything? I don't know much from html and I don't even know the right terminology so I can look in the internet. I did btw tried to make just a rounded background but I want to keep the radius of the rounds stable as I change the size of the cell/(or table).

Comment: I meant that you should have pointed out the code you have tried and put it in your question.

Comment: another thing that will help you understand of what I want is visiting this site: http://edition.cnn.com/ on the bottom you will several boxes with a grey box for tile and a shadow. I know that I have to use some pictures for the rounds and the corners and the inside elements must be somehow repeat themselves.  thank you again for your help. you can post a link to a tutorial perhaps. that would help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are not supposed to be used to build a layout. So the valid way would be to use i.e. `<div>`:

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div>
        <img src="a.jpg">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.article {
    /* Shadow around the whole box */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;

    /* Repeat rounder borders here, so shadow will be rounded as well */
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;

    /* Background gradient. In browser with no gradient support, fallback to orange */
    background: orange;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, orange, yellow);
}

div.article > div {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

[JSFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/SkVyx/2/).

**Note**: this example will render shadow and gradient in Chrome/Safari (and other webkit browsers) only because, for simplicity, I've skipped other vendor prefixes. Add them tu provide support for other browsers as well.

Comment: a very good one.. how can I do the same by adding custom background? :) thank you again .. I know that I have to design the background and keep the rounds (right and left) and then repeat the middle.. but how do i do it? :)

Comment: @Mdermez - what custom backround? The color? Image? And where should it appear?

Comment: image of course. I will have to design a background and integrate it into the table and add text. the background elements will be rounded so these will be the left and the right of the "title" box. in the middle in order to preserve the same graphic I will have to repeat a visually similar graphic.. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mdermez - to be honest I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: check your example. In the place you have the yellow color I want to place a yellow background with gradients and shadow. So I have to add an image as a background. but instead of forming rounds with your method my image will aready have rouned corners. So to create your yellow bar I have to take 3 images and put them in line as a background. 2 of them will be used as left and right corner ( the rounded corners) and the middle one will be repeating itself so I change the width of my table it wont change the aspect ratio of the rest images. (check my url in my initial post)  :)

Comment: @Mdermez - if you need shadow and gradient, you can still achieve it without background image. See my updated answer and jsFiddle.

Comment: thank you .. I will use this method but I would like also a method with images. because in most cases we use gradients and patterns that cannot designed with html coding.

Comment: also with what browsers is this compatible?

Comment: Having quick look at [caniiuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) it'll be supported in modern Chrome, Firefox and Safari. When it comes to IE, shadows and rounder corners are supported from IE9 and gradient from IE10.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
table#yourtableid tr:first-of-type {
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
} 
</style>
```

Gives a 20px border radius to a specified table's first row top left and top right corner.